# How to make my twitter bootstrap overlap all other elements?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I've implemented twitter bootstrap however it wasn't able to overlap all the other element in the webapp which result into something like this.

[image]

This is how i implement my bootstrap

```
<div id="twitterbootstrap">
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
<div class="navbar-inner">
    <div class="container">
        <a class="btn btn-navbar" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".nav-collapse">
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </a>
        <a class="brand" href="#">iPolice's Menu</a>
        <div class="nav-collapse">
            <ul class="nav">
                <li class="divider-vertical"></li>
                <li><a href="AdminVerifyMemberAccount.aspx">VerifyMemberAccount</a></li>
                <li class="divider-vertical"></li>
                <li><a href="AdminAddAccount.aspx">AddAccount</a></li>
                <li class="divider-vertical"></li>
                <li><a href="AdminDropAccount.aspx">Drop Account</a></li>
                <li class="divider-vertical"></li>
                <li><a href="AdminEditProfile.aspx">Edit Account</a></li>
                <li class="divider-vertical"></li>
                <li><a href="AdminColdStorage.aspx">Cold Account</a></li>
                <li class="divider-vertical"></li>
                <li><a href="AdminLogout.aspx">Logout</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Css

```
#twitterbootstrap {
  position:relative;
}
```

I searched other thread and all recommended position:relative which i added in the CSS but it doesn't work.

I also tried added this which didn't work as well.

```
overflow:visible;
```

Here's a sample of the bootstrap not overlapping any elements

http://bootply.com/103006

Comment: So, you're trying to have a fixed navbar? Which version of Bootstrap are you using?

Comment: Plz add jsfiddle for this

Comment: @Rubyist is it even possible to add my twitterbootstrap on a jsfiddle?

Comment: @TiesonT. i'm using v2.3.2

Comment: Try this site : http://bootply.com/

Comment: Yes, you can use a CDN to load the Bootstrap resources into a jsFiddle: http://www.bootstrapcdn.com/#legacy_tab

Comment: Thanks. Here's the [link](http://bootply.com/103006) for my jsfiddle. I spammed the way "TEST" to show that the twitter bootstrap isn't overlapping. Shall add it up to my question as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#twitterbootstrap {
  position:relative;
    z-index:1000000;
}
```

try this... it will work... you need to provide z-index so that overlap will not occure.